# gitweb refusing to blame

Tags: debian, configuration, git

I'm attempting to get gitweb (git 1.8.4.2, via `git instaweb`) in a project dir on my Debian server to offer blame views.

In my `/etc/gitweb.conf`:

```
… # default logo, favicon, etc. settings

$feature{'blame'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'pickaxe'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'snapshot'}{'default'} = ['tgz', 'txz', 'zip'];
$feature{'highlight'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'pathinfo'}{'default'} = [1];
```

In my global config file:

```
[gitweb]
    blame = true
    snapshot = tgz, txz, zip
    patches = 256
    avatar = gravatar
[instaweb]
    local = false
    httpd = apache2 -f
    port = 4321
```

In my project's `.git/config` file:

```
[gitweb]
        blame = true
```

And yet, when I try to load a git blame view *(via hand-modifying the URL to `http://myserversip:4321/?p=.git;a=blame;f=Tests/InchCoordProxyTests.m;h=b4b2…;hb=53b4`, since blame action links don't show up)*:

[image]

Doing a quick search for “*Blame view not allowed*” in the `gitweb.cgi` source reveals plainly that the `gitweb_check_feature('blame')` conditional is failing.

---

**What am I doing wrong?**

Or, is there a way to verbosely print out why gitweb is doing what it's doing (e.g. which config files were read, which settings were loaded from each file, etc.)?

Comment: 403 indicates a permission issue. What happens in the apache error logs `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` when you reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `git-instaweb.sh`, it doesn't seem to read `/etc/gitweb.conf` but `$GIT_DIR/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl`, so you'll need to edit that file.

Comment: No dice.  Just tried adding the config feature lines to the project's gitweb_config.perl and stop/starting the server— same error.

Comment: Editing that file get rewriten on each run of git-instaweb. That is why it doesn't capture changes made to it

Answer (score 0):

For this to work with instaweb I do the following instead. Maybe a custom script or alias would help.

```
git instaweb
cat >> .git/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl <<'EOF'
$feature{'highlight'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'blame'}{'default'} = [1];
EOF
```

Just know that next time instaweb starts it will overwrite that file and will need to append your customization again.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently found a similar problem while dealing with an AppArmour issue in OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

`git instaweb` will create and overwrite the configuration file `.git/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl` ($GITWEB_CONFIG), so it is not possible to store configuration here.

Looking in `gitweb.cgi`, we can see that there are two other canditates for configuration:

1. `/etc/gitweb-common.conf` (`GITWEB_CONFIG_COMMON`)
2. `/etc/gitweb.conf` (`$GITWEB_CONFIG_SYSTEM`)

The relevant code is this:

```
sub evaluate_gitweb_config {
    our $GITWEB_CONFIG = $ENV{'GITWEB_CONFIG'} || "/etc/gitweb.conf";
    our $GITWEB_CONFIG_SYSTEM = $ENV{'GITWEB_CONFIG_SYSTEM'} || "/etc/gitweb.conf";
    our $GITWEB_CONFIG_COMMON = $ENV{'GITWEB_CONFIG_COMMON'} || "/etc/gitweb-common.conf";

    # Protect against duplications of file names, to not read config twice.
    # Only one of $GITWEB_CONFIG and $GITWEB_CONFIG_SYSTEM is used, so
    # there possibility of duplication of filename there doesn't matter.
    $GITWEB_CONFIG = ""        if ($GITWEB_CONFIG eq $GITWEB_CONFIG_COMMON);
    $GITWEB_CONFIG_SYSTEM = "" if ($GITWEB_CONFIG_SYSTEM eq $GITWEB_CONFIG_COMMON);

    # Common system-wide settings for convenience.
    # Those settings can be overridden by GITWEB_CONFIG or GITWEB_CONFIG_SYSTEM.
    read_config_file($GITWEB_CONFIG_COMMON);

    # Use first config file that exists.  This means use the per-instance
    # GITWEB_CONFIG if exists, otherwise use GITWEB_SYSTEM_CONFIG.
    read_config_file($GITWEB_CONFIG) and return;
    read_config_file($GITWEB_CONFIG_SYSTEM);
}
```

We can conclude that:

1. `/etc/gitweb-common.conf` is always read
2. `/etc/gitweb.conf` is never read if `.git/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl` is read.

That way, the only place to put persistent configuration is in `/etc/gitweb-common.conf` (or $GITWEB_CONFIG_COMMON).

So, long story short, rename your `/etc/gitweb.conf` file to `/etc/gitweb-common.conf` and try again.

However, do notice that your distribution may have a problem with AppArmour, as I had with mine. If that is the case, please see the details on  how to solve it in this post: [Problem with `git instaweb` on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed: /etc/gitweb-common.conf is not being read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77789216/problem-with-git-instaweb-on-opensuse-tumbleweed-etc-gitweb-common-conf-is-n)